# Why am I getting no matching function call error?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to call a pointer to member function and not knowing why it's not working. Here are the errors:

> prog.cpp: In function `‘int main()’`:
>   prog.cpp:16:19: error: no matching function for call to `‘foo(A, int (A::*)())’`
>   prog.cpp:16:19: note: candidate is:
>   prog.cpp:4:6: note: `template<class A, class B> decltype ((declval<A>)().*(declval<B>)()) foo(A&&, B&&)`
>   prog.cpp:4:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
>   prog.cpp: In substitution of `‘template<class A, class B> decltype ((declval<A>)().*(declval<B>)()) foo(A&&, B&&) [with A = A; B = int (A::*)()]’`:
>   prog.cpp:16:19:   required from here
>   prog.cpp:4:6: error: invalid use of non-static member function

```
#include <utility>

template <typename A, typename B>
auto foo(A&& a, B&& b) -> decltype(std::declval<A>().*(std::declval<B>()))
{
    return (std::forward<A>(a)).*(std::forward<B>(b));
}

struct A
{
    int f() { return 0; }
};

int main()
{
    foo(A(), &A::f);
}
```

---

**Update:**

I changed the code in response to the comments/answers and this is what I have:

```
template <typename A, typename B>
auto foo(A&& a, B&& b) -> decltype((std::declval<A>().*(std::declval<B>()))())
{
    return (std::forward<A>(a)).*(std::forward<B>(b))();
}
```

But when I call it this is what it's returning:

> prog.cpp: In instantiation of `‘decltype ((declval<A>)().*(declval<B>)()()) foo(A&&, B&&) [with A = A; B = int (A::*)(); decltype ((declval<A>)().*(declval<B>)()()) = int]’`:
>   prog.cpp:16:19:   required from here
>   prog.cpp:6:55: error: must use `‘.*’` or `‘->*’` to call pointer-to-member function in 
> `‘std::forward<int (A::*)()>((* & b)) (...)’, e.g. ‘(... ->* std::forward<int (A::*)()>((* & b))) (...)’`
>   prog.cpp: In function `‘decltype ((declval<A>)().*(declval<B>)()()) foo(A&&, B&&) [with A = A; B = int (A::*)(); decltype ((declval<A>)().*(declval<B>)()()) = int]’`:
>   prog.cpp:7:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: The `declval` function doesn't take any parameters.

Comment: You are missing parentheses around the expression between `return` and `()`; you should write `return ((std::forward<A>(a)).*(std::forward<B>(b))) ();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit simpler, than you coded. And you've forgotten to *call* your function:

```
template <typename A, typename B>
auto foo(A&& a, B&& b) -> decltype((a.*b)())
{
    return ((std::forward<A>(a)).*(std::forward<B>(b)))();
}
```

Comment: That should work. My g++ (probably old), however, gives me `sorry, unimplemented: mangling dotstar_expr`

Comment: @JohnB, I use `gcc 4.7.0`, it's not too recent, also.

Comment: @JohnB, I could propose [this](http://ideone.com/XIw5FV), but I think It would actually be off-topic.

Comment: I guess this will do. Thanks.